# Error with snakemake when combining --use-singularity and --use-conda: "/bin/sh: 1: conda: not found"

Tags: python, conda, snakemake

I have an analysis pipeline using snakemake where one rule requires a singularity container, and several others require conda environments. I specify the "container:" and "conda:" directives where needed within the Snakefile.

The way snakemake is invoked is a little complex. For various reasons, I invoke the snakemake API via a custom script within a conda environment, with both "use_conda=True" and "use_singularity=True" specified in the config. The pipeline has completed with no issues in the past, but someone recently reinstalled the pipeline, and now I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: conda: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cfos/miniconda3/envs/CIS/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 726, in snakemake
    success = workflow.execute(
  File "/home/cfos/miniconda3/envs/CIS/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 978, in execute
    dag.create_conda_envs(
  File "/home/cfos/miniconda3/envs/CIS/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 313, in create_conda_envs
    env.create(dryrun)
  File "/home/cfos/miniconda3/envs/CIS/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 391, in create
    pin_file = self.pin_file
  File "/home/cfos/miniconda3/envs/CIS/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snakemake/common/__init__.py", line 192, in __get__
    value = self.method(instance)
  File "/home/cfos/miniconda3/envs/CIS/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 107, in pin_file
    f".{self.conda.platform}.pin.txt"
  File "/home/cfos/miniconda3/envs/CIS/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snakemake/common/__init__.py", line 192, in __get__
    value = self.method(instance)
  File "/home/cfos/miniconda3/envs/CIS/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 102, in conda
    return Conda(self._container_img)
  File "/home/cfos/miniconda3/envs/CIS/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 648, in __init__
    shell.check_output(
  File "/home/cfos/miniconda3/envs/CIS/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snakemake/shell.py", line 63, in check_output
    return sp.check_output(cmd, shell=True, executable=executable, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cfos/miniconda3/envs/CIS/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/home/cfos/miniconda3/envs/CIS/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command ' singularity --quiet --silent exec --home /home/cfos/Programs/COVID_Illumina_Snakemake  /home/cfos/Programs/COVID_Illumina_Snakemake/.snakemake/singularity/1ad1f7122bf7704a6b02b6359ede7533.simg sh -c 'conda info --json'' returned non-zero exit status 127.
```

I get the same error if I run the `snakemake` command 'manually' (outside of my script) like so:

```
snakemake -j20 --use-conda --use-singularity -s /path/to/Snakefile --config [OPTIONS]
```

It appears like `snakemake` is checking for the presence of `conda` within a singularity container that I have only specified for one rule. This is not the desired behaviour, since conda is not within that container. Instead, snakemake should be detecting and using the system installation of miniconda, and the the installation of mamba within the conda environment from which I run the pipeline. This is the way the pipeline used to run with no problems.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? The confusing thing is that I've tried various versions of snakemake, including ones that worked well previously, and I still get the error.

**Details**

snakemake v7.8.5

conda 4.11.0

If it helps to understand the way I invoke the pipeline: https://github.com/charlesfoster/covid-illumina-snakemake

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a bug in a recent version of snakemake.  Can you try an earlier version to confirm?  If so, open an issue on the [snakemake github](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues).

Comment: What happens if you comment out one (`conda:` or `container:`) in the two rules (`update_nextclade` and `nextclade`) that have both options? Seems like those should just have the `container:` option.

Comment: @merv you're spot on - thanks. Removing the conda option led to the containers being used as desired, and the pipeline finishing. I'll consider making an issue regardless to perhaps get a more informative error message or a warning when both conda and container directives have been assigned to a rule.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be resolved by having a global singularity container with conda and mamba: `container: "docker://continuumio/miniconda3:23.10.0-1"` not inside any rule but on its own.

What happens is although snakemake is trying to use one of your local singularity env to activate conda. This is definitely not an expected issue. But providing a global container can prevent snakemake from looking for the conda in a container that doesn't have it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).